# How to send data to server from html component in JSF

Tags: javascript, html, jsf-2

I have a CKEditor in my page. Like this

```
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

    <script language="JavaScript">

        function comeBack(){
            document.getElementById(editorValue).value = this.value;
        }

    </script>

</h:head>

<h:body >

    <h:form id="ckEditorForm" prependId="false" >

        <textarea id="editor1"
                  name="editor1"
                  onblur="alert(document.getElementById(editorValue).value = this.value);">

        </textarea>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
        </script>

        <h:inputHidden value="#{editorBean.value}" id="editorValue" />

        <h:commandButton id="submit"
                         value="Submit"
                         action="welcome.xhtml" />


    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EditorBean {

    private String value;

    /** Creates a new instance of EditorBean */
    public EditorBean() {

    } //end of constructor

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        System.out.println("Content: "+value);
        System.out.println();

    }

} //end of class EditorBean
```

Now i want that user press the submit button then the editor  value is save into my bean. I found this hiddenfield technique suggested by some one on this forum , but it is not working. Am i doing something wrong? How can i achieve what i want?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can write your own composite JSF component that utilizes CKEDITOR on the client side?  Here is a good tutorial on how to write a composite component.  http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/composite-components-in-jsf-2-0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that JSF is a HTML code generator and that JavaScript has basically only access to the HTML DOM tree, not the JSF source code.

Open the page in browser, rightclick and choose *View Source*. Locate the generated HTML of the `<h:inputHidden>` component. It'll look something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ckEditorForm:editorValue" name="ckEditorForm:editorValue" value="" />
```

Please note the `id` attribute value. You have to use **exactly** this value in your JavaScript `document.getElementById()`:

```
document.getElementById("ckEditorForm:editorValue");
```

By the way, much easier is to just use `<h:inputTextarea>` instead:

```
<h:inputTextarea id="editor1" value="#{editorBean.value}" />
<script>CKEDITOR.replace("ckEditorForm:editor1");</script>
```

Comment: this isn't working `<h:form id="ckEditorForm" prependId="" >
       <h:inputTextarea id="editor1" value="#{editorBean.value}" />
      <script>
          CKEDITOR.replace("ckEditorForm:editor1");
      </script>

  <h:commandButton id="save" value="Save" action="welcome.xhtml" />

  </h:form>`  It shows normal text area, instead of CkEditor

Comment: when i do view source, then i get this `<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="6713004186034026806:1751224147377468677" autocomplete="off" />`Why here id attribute is different ?

Comment: Are there any JS errors in browser's JS console? Perhaps your ckeditor.js is simply not loaded at all. The view state hidden field is completely unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Hi problem soved. It should be                                      `<h:inputTextarea id="editor1" value="#{editorBean.value}" />
 <script>
     CKEDITOR.replace("editor1");
 </script>`   Thanks :)

Comment: Ah right, you're using `prependId="false"`. I didn't expect that (this is usually a poor practice).

Comment: Oh,why `prependId="false"` is poor practice?

Comment: @Basit: dont use `prependId="false"`. You will mostly like have a id collision when you build small module, and ui:include them into a bigger xhtml file

Answer (score -1):

```
client side:
call this function from your component
function send() {
var imageData = "Anand";
//call remotecommand
passToJSFManagedBean([ {
name : 'imagedata',
value : imageData
} ]);
//Prime faces component
<p:remoteCommand name="passToJSFManagedBean"
action="#{guestPhotoRegiCardMB.onCapture()}" process="@this" />
```

Server side:
onCapture(){
...
String imagedata = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("imagedata");
.....
}